# Independence of functions inside a specific interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While solving problems about differential equations and Wronskian ,  I encounter this question a lot :

prove that the two functions y1(x) and y2(x) are independent on a specific given interval .

My question :

what is the importance of the given interval ? are there any functions that are independent/dependent in a specific interval of x only ?!

Can you give me an example ?